# converting each column list element to JSON in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to convert a pandas dataframe column of list elements to json and push it to snowflake as a variant but I'm stuck in 1st step.

I have a pandas dataframe with ID and conversation transcript which looks in this way.

Sample dataframe:

```
ID   transcript
1     ['Joe(joe@email.com): Hey', 'Smoe(smoe@email.com): Hey!! How are you doing?', 'Joe(joe@email.com): I'm doing good']
```

And, I have multiple rows(conversation transcripts with different ID) with same format

Expected dataframe:

```
    ID   transcript
    1     {'Joe(joe@email.com): Hey', 'Smoe(smoe@email.com): Hey!! How are you doing?', 'Joe(joe@email.com): I'm doing good'}
```

I tried to convert each individual object to json but list object has no attribute 'to_json'

```
df['transcript_json'] = df['transcript_json'].apply(lambda x: x.to_json())
```

I also tried converting the whole column into a json object which gave me a big string object but didn't get me any further where I want to go.

```
transcript_list = df['transcript'].to_json()

{"0":["Joe(joe@email.com): Hey", "Smoe(smoe@email.com): Hey!! How are you doing?", "Joe(joe@email.com): I'm doing good"]}
```

I know I'm missing something small here. Any ideas on how to do it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Apparently, your expected dataframe contains an invalid JSON. If you need multi-values, you need to use an array instead of dict. For instance, the expected JSON would be: `['Joe(joe@email.com): Hey', 'Smoe(smoe@email.com): Hey!! How are you doing?', 'Joe(joe@email.com): I'm doing good']`

Comment: Ah...  I see. That makes sense. I don't have a key for that JSON object

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what are wanting the end result to be. Your expected from original only change these [] to these {}. If you want a dictionary with usable key:value pairs, here's a bastardized way to change the string to dictionary. The problem is, you lose any elements when the email address (the key) is the same.

```
data='''
ID   transcript
1   ['Joe(joe@email.com): Hey', 'Smoe(smoe@email.com): Hey!! How are you doing?', 'Joe(joe@email.com): I'm doing good']
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='   ', engine='python')
df['transcript'] = df['transcript'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(': ', '": "').replace("['", '{"').replace("']", '"}').replace("', '", '", "'))
print(df['transcript'].apply(lambda x: type(x)))
df['transcript'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x))
```

Outptut

```
0    <class 'str'>
Name: transcript, dtype: object

0    {'Joe(joe@email.com)': 'I'm doing good', 'Smoe(smoe@email.com)': 'Hey!! How are you doing?'}
Name: transcript, dtype: object
```

What format do you need that list object to really be in so you don't lose any data? Can it be a list of properly formatted key:value pairs?

Answer (score 1):

Split each item in the list on `:` and create dictionary out of each key,value after splitting and then use json.dumps to serialize it to JSON string.

```py
df.transcript.apply(lambda x:{key:value.strip() for key,value in [item.split(':') for item in x]}).apply(json.dumps)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
'{"Joe(joe@email.com)": "I\'m doing good", "Smoe(smoe@email.com)": "Hey!! How are you doing?"}'
```